# Any good plugin or workaround to sync 2 Backbone models with the same id?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Here is my problem, on my application, 2 different views instantiate the same model with same id. I would like the 2 models to be the same or to be sync (fire events on change). Any idea?

I took a look at Backbone-relational but people are too much complaining about it.

Comment: instantiate the model at a higher view level and pass the one model to both views. in the views, reference `this.model` and it will keep the other one in sync

Comment: Thanks for your answer but doing that is not possible in my context.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution with no additional dependencies would be to design the application in such a way that the views in question share a common auxiliary `Collection`, perhaps as a global/module-scoped variable or passed in as constructor parameter. This collection would serve as definite store for models of a particular type, and by checking it you can avoid creating the same model twice:

```
var model = App.sharedCollection.get(id);
if (!model) {
    model = App.sharedCollection.add({id: id});
}
```

If you prefer a pre-built solution, you can use the [Backbone.ModelFactory](https://github.com/misteroneill/backbone-model-factory) library, which automates this deduplication. With this Backbone plugin, you simply use `Backbone.ModelFactory` instead of `Backbone.Model.extend` to define your models, and duplication is automatically taken care of. Here is an example extracted from the `README`:

```
var User = Backbone.ModelFactory({
  defaults: {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
  }
});

var user1 = new User({id: 1});
var user2 = new User({id: 1});
var user3 = new User({id: 2});

console.log(user1 === user2); // true
console.log(user3 === user1); // false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The idea first was to not implementing such a solution (but I think I'll have to). The plugin Backbone.ModelFactory doesn't look to be maintain anymore and doesn't support Backbone 1.x.x versions

Comment: It might save time if you fork `ModelFactory` and update it for Backbone 1.x rather than rolling your own. Others with a similar problem will thank you. :)